# issues in compiling the-graph

Tags: the-graph

I have a Factory contract which is used for creating three types of smart contracts. Each of these contracts has the same `OwnershipTransferred` event, and so I was trying to avoid code duplication in my mappings and have the event handler code in one place.

So, I created a `utils.ts` file with the code and now I'm trying to use this in all three event handlers in mapping files.

I'm not able to do this because I get compilation errors from TypeScript when I run `graph build`. I tried using `any`, `unknown`, `EventType1 | EventType2 | EventType3`, `ethereum.Event` as the type of **event** parameter but none worked.

Code

```
export function ownershipTransferredHelper(event: any): void {
  const toOwner = event.params.newOwner;
  const fromOwner = event.params.previousOwner;

  let entity = new Ownership(
    event.transaction.hash.concatI32(event.logIndex.toI32())
  );

  entity.previousOwner = fromOwner;
  entity.newOwner = toOwner;

  ...

  entity.save();
}
```